# Postgres join jsonb column

Tags: postgresql

I have a left table that looks like this

```
+-----------+-----------------------+
| name      | interests             |
+-----------+-----------------------+
| Jason     | ["sports", "food"]    |
+-----------+-----------------------+
```

And another table that has the interest information.

```
+-----------+----------------------------+
| interest  | items                      |
+-----------+----------------------------+
| sports    | ["football", "swimming"]   |
+-----------+----------------------------+
| food      | ["pasta", "bread"]         |
+-----------+----------------------------+
| news      | ["BBC", "New York Times"]  |
+-----------+----------------------------+
```

How could I now make a query so that I can obtain an output like this?
Basically something like in Python, we would iterate over the `interests` and get all the `items` belong to those `interests`.

Many thanks.

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+
| name      | items                                       |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+
| Jason     | ["football", "swimming", "pasta", "bread"]  |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Never store attributes that you want to join on in an array or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a questionable database design. A traditional many-to-many table would probably make more sense.

However, to achieve what you want, you need to unnest the all elements from the `interest` table for all interests from the person table. Then aggregate them back into a JSON array:

```
select p.name,
       i.interests
from person p 
   left join lateral (
       select jsonb_agg(ix.item) as interests
       from interest i
          cross join jsonb_array_elements(i.items) as ix(item)
       where p.interests ? i.interest
   ) as i on true
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a1ec5c3c050ceb5d81b33864dd531246)

---

A slightly more compact version can be achieved, by defining your own aggregate that appends multiple jsonb values (rather than creating an array of arrays as `jsonb_agg()` would do if done on the "raw" arrays).

```
create aggregate jsonb_append_agg(jsonb) 
(
  sfunc = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
  stype = jsonb
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select p.name,
       i.interests
from person p 
   left join lateral (
       select jsonb_append_agg(i.items) as interests
       from interest i
       where p.interests ? i.interest
   ) as i on true;
```